# how to calculate communication waste in Scrum ?

Tags: scrum, communication, real-time

communication waste is the time spent in communication between team members in the following cases:

1. delivering features which are not needed by the customer
2. delivering partial features (analysis, design, or testing is done, but the    feature is canceled before it is completed and delivered)

Any other type of communication should be productive, even if it can be squeezed a bit.

can any one give an advice how to calculate these 2 items mentioned above

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to measure these things? Do you have a problem with either delivering unneeded features or having features canceled before they are completed? After you get your measurements, what do you intend to do?

Comment: compare the communication waste between using Scrum and any other method

Comment: Why are you so interested in waste in communication? The excess communication, especially in the two cases that you mention, are actually symptoms of other problems in the development process. Why focus on communication rather than other things, which are more well understood?

Comment: #1 isn't a "communication waste" -- you're wasting development time too. Do you not care about the time spent _developing_ features not needed by the customer, and why are you building such features?

Comment: If your development team is spending their time delivering features that are not needed, it seems to me you have communication _deficiency_, not communication waste.

Answer (score 2):

There are significant flaws in the reasoning behind this question.

1. What is the reason for assuming that intra-team communication around cancelled features is "communication waste". That term implies that those communications were a waste of time, which is unlikely to be true for at least some of those communications, as they will have beneficial side effects.
2. What is the reason for only wanting to measure "communication waste", as opposed to all wasted time?
3. In order to measure "communication waste", you'll need a way of measuring communication time for all tasks. Are you going to strap microphones to your devs and record everything for later analysis? If not, then you'll struggle to get accurate and meaningful figures.

I'd suggest you turn the whole thing on its head and start by investigating why tasks get cancelled. Address that and the whole issue of "communication waste" becomes moot.

Answer (score 2):

I think that trying to measure communication would be [waste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muda_(Japanese_term)), in the Lean sense. It's incredibly difficult to do. The easiest way to do it would be self-reporting, but that adds unnecessary overhead to actually completing the work at hand. Instead, I'd focus on eliminating things that can cause additional communication.

> delivering features which are not needed by the customer

You can eliminate this by ensuring that all work is part of an active task. Your question specifically mentions Scrum, so every team member should only be working on stories that are part of the current Sprint. If the team finishes the work allocated to the Sprint, they should work with the Product Owner to determine what, if anything, is able to be brought into the Sprint. This may include the team deciding to pay down technical debt.

The Product Owner should be actively prioritizing the Product Backlog and working with the team at the start of the Sprint to bring things into the Sprint Backlog. If this is done right and the team sticks to the plan defined by the Sprint Goal and Sprint Backlog, then there shouldn't be any work that is not needed being done.

> delivering partial features (analysis, design, or testing is done, but the feature is canceled before it is completed and delivered)

This one is more difficult. The agile methods embrace change, but it can be disruptive to the team if there are too many changes within a Sprint. Part of the role of the Scrum Master is to train and educate stakeholders on the process, which may include the Product Owner. Sufficient work should be done to define and prioritize the items in the Product Backlog to ensure that the high priority items are the ones being worked on.

> Any other type of communication should be productive, even if it can be squeezed a bit.

I would advise against trying to reduce constructive communication. Communication is sharing knowledge among the team, which leads to a cross-functional team that understands more of the product. However, you do need to balance the overhead of communication with the internal benefits.

Answer (score 0):

This is product development waste on the wrong features.

It could be avoided by *better* communication.

> Communication waste

is two words put together that, in practical terms, mean nothing to me from working in several different agile environments, although they appear to have a specific meaning in Lean or Six Sigma based on the feedback below.

Comment: The [term "waste" does have a specific meaning, especially in Lean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muda_(Japanese_term)) - it's non-value added activities. Coupled with the emphasis in the question on measuring, I wouldn't be surprised if the asker was in an environment that was based on Lean and/or Six Sigma.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, as per your answer, measuring communication would be a waste, in any sense, not just that of lean. Ergo there is no non-wasteful way of determining "Communication waste" and thus the term has no effective meaning as Michael suggests.

Comment: @DavidArno I don't know how you get that impression. The term "communication waste" does have a specific meaning. However, in nearly all cases, this is a by-product of other wastes. It's better to measure and fix those at the root cause. There are methods for measuring communication and determining if it's a bottleneck, but none will solve the problems presented in the question.

Comment: well that is is totally true there are methods for measuring communication and determining if it's a bottleneck. and I do have a problem to calculate un-added value. daily scrum meetings , time spent on whole sprint planning ,using documentation to communicate in a distributed environment this could be a challenge . previous studies shows that dev take 75% of their time communicating. how to calculate the time waste of tools used for communication and un needed communication practices is scrum. cause yes from working in a lean environment it  is better for distributed teams

Comment: Updated my answer based on the feedback.  Maybe the three downvoter will consider.

Comment: @MahaYacoub, "previous studies shows that dev take 75% of their time communicating". You totally made that figure up!

Comment: @DavidArno no sir I got it from a research paper ... but the author did not show how ...

Comment: @DavidArno !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! sir am searching for help to to fight . here is the link http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~beki/c13.pdf ... and there is what is called "communication waste" here is one of the articles u could rean http://www.leancpa.net/is-your-communication-lean ... by transforming from scrum to a lean method,u eliminate un added value that may found as waste such as daily meetings,working in time box sprint ...when u get professional one day in work u will understand that Scrum might be kind of micromanagement but lean carriage developers to work faster and better with rapped changes

Comment: @MahaYacoub, thanks for the link. So you didn't completely make up your 75% figure, you simply incorrectly remembered "The  developers  in  their  study spent  an  average  of  75  minutes each  day  in unplanned interpersonal interaction." as "previous studies shows that dev take 75% of their time communicating". Highlights why it's as important to remember the units as the figure :)
”

Comment: @MahaYacoub, "...when u get professional one day in work u will understand..." A basic measure of professionalism is whether one is able to write like an adult; or like a 12 year-old. Generally "you" is considered more professional than "u". Just saying...